# There is no row at position 0, C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Hello Fellow Developers,
I am trying to return a Datatable from a function to be used for my code.
Its a login table, where i have my employeeroles, and based upon the employeerole i am doing my further navigation.
But the problem is whenever i try to fire the query, the query fires and returns some value in the dataTable but when i try to access it, the Error: "There is no row at position 0" pops up.

I am checking the DataTable if its null or not.

The Initialization of DatabaseConnection class and its object creation can be found here and My Function (class declaration, constructor and the function )

```
public class DatabaseConnection
{
    const string strConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE =dilbert.humber.ca:1521/grok; USER ID =n00993435; PASSWORD= oracle;";
    OracleConnection oracleConnection;
    OracleCommand oracleCommand;
    string query;
    OracleDataReader oracleReader;
    OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter;
    OracleCommandBuilder oracleCommandBuilder;
    DataTable dataTable;

    public DatabaseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(strConnectionString);
            oracleCommand = new OracleCommand();
            oracleCommand.Connection = oracleConnection;
            oracleCommand.Connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
public DataTable Login(string u, string p)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "select employeeid, username, password, firstname, lastname, employeerole from login where username='" + u + "' and password='" + p + "'";
            oracleCommand.CommandText = query;
            oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand);
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My Implementation:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUName.Text == null || txtUName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter UserName");
        }
        else if (txtPassword.Text == null || txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Password");
        }
        else
        {
            string username = txtUName.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;
            DatabaseConnection obj = new DatabaseConnection();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = obj.Login(username, password);
            if (dt == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("User with these credentials not found in our Database. Please contact the Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
                string role = row[5].ToString();
                if (role == "ADMIN")
                {
                    Admin madmin = new Admin();
                    this.Hide();
                    madmin.Show();
                }
            else if (role == "MANAGER")
            {
                BranchManager badmin = new BranchManager();
                this.Hide();
                badmin.Show();
            }
            else if (role == "EMPLOYEE")
            {
                MainBank obj2 = new MainBank();
                obj2.Show();
                this.Hide();

            }
            else
            {
                lblWarning.Visible = true;
                lblWarning.Text = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
                txtUName.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtPassword.BackColor = Color.Red;
                txtUName.Focus();
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Data is properly retrieved in Oracle :
[image]

I am Clueless as to why this error is popping up.

This is the Query that is created : `"select employeeid, username, password, firstname, lastname, employeerole from login where username='ADMIN' and password='ADMIN'"` This one seems fine to me as i tried to run the same on the editor and it works! Is there something i am missing??

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dt == null only checks if the DataTable is not null.You should check if the count of dt.Rows. If if is zero you will get IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 3):

It looks like no records from the database results in an empty `DataTable`, not a `null` one.

Check to make sure there is at least one row before you try to access it.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("User with these credentials not found in our Database. Please contact the Admin");
}
```

You have some stuff that's defined outside of your `Login` method, which should probably all be defined inside it, so you can be more assured that nothing else is negatively affecting your connection to the database.

This is untested, but should work. I parameterized your query, and removed the try/catch. (If there are any exceptions, handle them in whatever event or method you're calling calling `Login` from.)

```
public DataTable Login(string u, string p)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    var connectionString = "whatever";  // change this obviously :)
    var query = "select employeeid, username, password, firstname, lastname, employeerole from login where username = :username and password = :password";

    using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
    {
        oracleConnection.Open();

        using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(query, oracleConnection))
        {
            oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", u);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", p);

            using (var oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand))
            {
                oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }

        oracleConnection.Close();
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: But How come it returns me the query when i try it in oracle? could you please check my query or its implementation where I am firing the query?

Comment: This is the Query that is created : `"select employeeid, username, password, firstname, lastname, employeerole from login where username='ADMIN' and password='ADMIN'"`

This one seems fine to me as i tried to run the same on the editor and it works! Is there something i am missing??

Comment: The Format is `string query = "select employeeid, username, password, firstname, lastname, employeerole from login where username='" + u + "' and password='" + p + "'";`

Comment: Do you have any suggestions??

Comment: The datatable is shown as {}, the DataSet is null, the columns are retrieved, as in the results view has all the columns, but the Rows are empty :( Please help

Comment: Yes, The oracleConnection.Open() is called when i create DatabaseConnection Object. The connection string is also perfect as I have only one Database that i am connected to.. :(

Comment: I have added the DatabaseConnection object creation and its code. Please have a look. Sorry for bothering you so much! :(

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I guess i am too silly to commit the tables after inserting a row into it.. to for the trouble! found the solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is as the message says, you have no rows in your data table, so when you try and index `0` it is failing.

You need to make sure you are correctly populating your data table from your login function.

To avoid the error, you can simply check that a row has been returned.

```
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Any()) {
   // it has results.
}
```

Comment: But How come it returns me the query when i try it in oracle? could you please check my query or its implementation where I am firing the query?

Answer (score 0):

`dt == null` only checks if the `DataTable` is not null.
You should check if dt.Rows.Count == 0.

```
if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0)
```

If it's zero that means your query did not return any results.

Comment: But How come it returns me the query when i try it in oracle? could you please check my query or its implementation where I am firing the query?

Comment: @Shashank in Login method after dt.Fill, does your table has data, do you get an exception? I see you have the command, dataTable and others as class fields...you do something else with them?

Comment: After the fill method i do not get an exception the code works fine and takes me to the implementation of the code

Comment: The datatable i guess is returned as null. I am entering the proper column names to be retrieved and the direct method returns the query as well, i dunno whats wrong with c#

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Everyone! 
I found the answer and it was pretty silly of me.. :(
after adding the insert query i didn't commit it.. hence the C# code count find it..
after the commit the query is properly retrieved! :)
thanks a ton for the quick response!

All hail Developers!